# Venusian reflectors: how long and how big?

Tags: terraforming, planets

In the Venus terraforming Project in my future, humans, along with bombarding the planet with hydrogen to deliver water, must also reduce the temperature and shorten the day cycle. To do this, two huge disk-shaped reflectors are built in orbit around the day and night side of Venus, reflecting light away and onto the surface respectively. These rotate every 24 hours to create an apparent day/night cycle similar to earth’s.
What I want to know is, how wide would these disks have to be and how long would it take to build them?

Comment: It is unlikely you need to simulate a shorter day-night cycle during the terraforming process. IIRC, the process involves cooling the planet so that the CO2 atmosphere condenses down to an icy layer across the surface (something like 1 meter thick). It's counter productive to beam solar energy, via the day-night cycle, down onto the planet when you're trying to cool it substantially.

Comment: Since you're talking about undeveloped tech, it can be as efficient or inefficient as you want it to be. Several different schemes for reflectors have been proposed, each with different advantages and disadvantages. They would all yield different answers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming_of_Venus

Comment: You seem to be confusing two goals: cooling venus down and giving it a reasonable day/night cycle.  The first needs to be done before the second, and the two cannot be combined.

Answer (score 2):

It will probably take [several years to cool down Venus](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9185/how-long-it-takes-to-cool-a-planet), so you don't want any sunlight hitting Venus for a while. As such, you can have whatever day night cycle you want, since you're clearly not having a day night cycle for any scientific reason.